# Genitive case after quantity words

Tags: родительный-падеж

When should I use the genitive singular and when should I use the genitive plural after quantity words like **много** and **сколько**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's countable vs. uncountable. Use singular for uncountable objects, like `много снега` - a lot of snow, and plural for countable, like `много снежков` - many snowballs.

This is similar to much vs many in English.